# threading timer python problem with big interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, python-multithreading, intervals

When I put a large interval to execute the program ends without executed the given function (join Does not solve the problem)

```
from threading import Timer

class TimerThread:
    def __init__(self, delay_time, thread_function):
        self._delay_time = delay_time
        self._thread_function = thread_function
        self._timer = None

    def run_repeatedly(self):
        self._thread_function()
        self._timer = Timer(self._delay_time, self.run_repeatedly)
        self._timer.start()
        self._timer.join()

timer = TimerThread(60 * 60, self.func) 
timer.run_repeatedly()
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it seems to work (without `join`):

```
from threading import Timer

class TimerThread:
    def __init__(self, delay_time, thread_function):
        self._delay_time = delay_time
        self._thread_function = thread_function
        self._timer = None

    def run_repeatedly(self):
        self._thread_function()
        self._timer = Timer(self._delay_time, self.run_repeatedly)
        self._timer.start()
    
    def cancel(self):
        if self._timer is not None:
            self._timer.cancel()

def my_func():
    print("Hello")
    
timer = TimerThread(3600, my_func) 
timer.run_repeatedly()
```

Comment: thanks, same problem, unfortunately this is not the solution

Comment: Then you need to post a complete example of your code that produces the error. Otherwiese it is not possible to identify the problem.